# Subdomains for testing in local

Tags: python, django, subdomain

How can I test my new web application on local host with dynamic subdomains?

I know how manage it with Django, but I don't know how can I configure my local server, because I need to edit my [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) manual with a custom domain like:

```
127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 user.mydomain.com
```

I'm using Django with gunicorn. Besides testing my application manually by editing the `/etc/hosts` file like now, is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep editing the `hosts` file is the simplest solution.

Years ago, I wasted hours trying to set up a [zero-configuration network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) and then switched back to just editing the `hosts` file. It might be possible now, but it wasn't then.